# Redux doesn't return to my initial state, when logout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, dispatch, next.js13

After my redux dispatches the `logout` action, I want to reset to my initial state. I'm using `nextjs`, and I don't understand why my desired logout reducer in `authenticateSlice.js` doesn't execute. I was also using a `redux-persist` to keep my state persistent.

Here is my code from store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authenticateSlice from "./slices/authenticateSlice";
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist"; // import persistStore
import storage from "./storage";
import { encryptTransform } from "redux-persist-transform-encrypt";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  auth: authenticateSlice.reducer,
});

let transforms = null;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  const encrypt = encryptTransform({
    secretKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REDUX_SECRET,
    onError: function (error) {
      // Handle the error.
    },
  });
  transforms = [encrypt];
}

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: storage,
  transforms,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: [thunk],
});

let persistor = persistStore(store); // initialize persistor

export { store, persistor };
```

Here is my code from the `authenticateSlice.js` which I have the `logout` function to dispatch.

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { commonPostRequest } from "@/django-api/common/commonRequestAPI";
import { CommonPostHeader } from "@/django-api/common/commonHeadersAPI";

export const fetchUserLogin = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/login",
  async (arg, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const { username, password } = arg;
    try {
      const loginRequest = await commonPostRequest({
        body: { username: username, password: password },
        headers: CommonPostHeader,
        url: "http://localhost:8000/api/accounts_app/login",
      });
      if (loginRequest.data) {
        return loginRequest.data;
      } else {
        throw new Error(loginRequest.message);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return rejectWithValue(err.message);
    }
  }
);

export const logout = () => {
  return { type: "auth/logout" };
};

// loading: 'idle' | 'pending' | 'succeeded' | 'failed'
const initialState = {
  data: {},
  loading: "idle",
  message: "",
};

const authenticateSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchUserLogin.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = "pending";
      })
      .addCase(fetchUserLogin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = "succeeded";
        state.data = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(fetchUserLogin.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = "failed";
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(logout, (state) => {
        Object.assign(state, initialState);
      });
  },
});

export default authenticateSlice;
```

Lastly, here is my `Header` function component where I want to dispatch the `logout` action from slice or dispatch the logout function to return with my initial state.

```
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { Row, Col, Divider, notification } from "antd";
import styles from "./Header.module.scss";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import {
  toLocalZoneDateTime,
  getCurrentDateTimeStamp,
} from "../common/functions/datetime";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { logout } from "../../next-redux/slices/authenticateSlice";

const Header = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { user } = props;
  const router = useRouter();

  const currentDateTimeStamp = getCurrentDateTimeStamp();

  const handleLogoutClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("logout");
    dispatch(logout());
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <Col span={24}>
          <Row gutter={[8, 8]} className={styles.topBar}>
            <Col span={12}>
              <Typography variant="subtitle2" className={styles.topDate}>
                {toLocalZoneDateTime(currentDateTimeStamp)}
              </Typography>
            </Col>
            <Col span={12}>
              {user ? (
                <Typography align="right">
                  <a
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      handleLogoutClick(e);
                    }}
                    className={styles.topBarLinks}
                  >
                    Logout
                  </a>
                </Typography>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <Typography align="right">
                    {" "}
                    <Link href="/signin/" className={styles.topBarLinks}>
                      Sign-in
                    </Link>{" "}
                    <Link href="/signup/" className={styles.topBarLinks}>
                      Sign-up
                    </Link>
                  </Typography>
                </>
              )}
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

`logout` is a function, not an action object, so the extra reducer case isn't running.

```js
export const logout = () => {
  return { type: "auth/logout" };
};

...

.addCase(logout, (state) => { // <-- function, e.g. logout.type undefined
  Object.assign(state, initialState);
});
```

## Solution

The solution would be to declare `logout` as a created action via the [`createAction`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction) utility.

```js
import { createSlice, createAction, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { commonPostRequest } from "@/django-api/common/commonRequestAPI";
import { CommonPostHeader } from "@/django-api/common/commonHeadersAPI";

export const fetchUserLogin = createAsyncThunk(
  ...
);

export const logout = createAction("auth/logout");

const initialState = { ... };

const authenticateSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchUserLogin.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = "pending";
      })
      .addCase(fetchUserLogin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = "succeeded";
        state.data = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(fetchUserLogin.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = "failed";
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(logout, (state) => {
        return initialState;
      });
  },
});

export default authenticateSlice.reducer;
```

Or declare a `logout` reducer case which will generate the `logout` action that could be exported.

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { commonPostRequest } from "@/django-api/common/commonRequestAPI";
import { CommonPostHeader } from "@/django-api/common/commonHeadersAPI";

export const fetchUserLogin = createAsyncThunk(
  ...
);

const initialState = { ... };

const authenticateSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logout: (state) => {
      return initialState;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchUserLogin.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = "pending";
      })
      .addCase(fetchUserLogin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = "succeeded";
        state.data = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(fetchUserLogin.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = "failed";
        state.message = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export const { logout } = authenticateSlice.actions;

export default authenticateSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using redux persist so you have to logout in different way.

```js
import { persistor } from './store'

const handleLogout = () => {
  dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' })
  persistor.purge()
}
```

Comment: it worked!. but i need to refresh it before it happens to change my header back to Sign-in and Sign-up. Can you help me to avoid refreshing the page also?

Here is what i've did
 const handleLogoutClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("logout");
    dispatch(userLogout());
    persistor.purge();
    router.push("/");
  };

Comment: I think `purge` clears the entire persited data, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, [purge](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#persistor-object) only "purges state from disk and returns a promise", it doesn't do anything with the current Redux store's value in memory. This code wouldn't fix actually resetting the state slice like OP wants. It only works by blowing away the persisted value and when the page is reloaded there is nothing to re-hydrate the state with so the initial value is used.